# GIT - Is it possible to have 2 situation tracked files in different branch?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Let me explain my current situation.
I have a teamwork project in github.
I usually use Office's PC to commit and push to github.
And difficulties happens when i want to work from home, and couldn't yet commit my changes to github (master). And i will not bring the PC to my home.

Then i have idea to make my private account in bitbucket, and import repo from github to bitbucket. It's going smoothly.
Then my planning is, when i have un-finished work, i can push my work to my personal repo, then at home, i just pull the changes to my personal pc. Then when it's done, i just push back to my personal repo, then when I'm in office, i pulled from my personal repo.

I have tried create branch in PC's office, so i have 2 branches. Branch 1 (github), and Branch 2 (bitbucket-personalrepo).
I have un-finished work and not commited yet, then i checkout to branch 2. Then commit and push, but when i checkout back again to branch 1, my un-finished work is not tracked (or in this case i use Phpstorm, the files name not in blue color).

Is it possible to have 2 situation tracked files in different branch?
[image: drawing situation]

Or maybe there is another way to do like what i draw in the images.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't an answer, but is your employer comfortable with you taking office files and versioning them in a separate repository?  This could be considered a security hazard (my employer would not allow this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a branch from master and just push there your unfinished work

```
git checkout -b MY-BRANCH
```

You can clone your GitHub repository from your home's PC, change to MY-BRANCH and push to your branch until your work is finished.

```
git checkout MY-BRANCH
```

Once you're done, you can just merge your branch back to the master branch

```
git checkout master
git merge MY-BRANCH
git push
```

This approach is useful even if you don't want to work from home, because you are preventing data loss if your PC crashes.

After this you can delete your separate branch again. You can delete your branches this way

```
git branch -d MY-BRANCH # Deletes local branch
git push origin :MY-BRANCH # Deletes remote branch
```